# Return Reference to a member field / property

Tags: c#

I am trying to change some repetitive code where the same operations apply to 2 variables : var A or var B.Currently i have something like this:

```
if(condition)
{
    if(varA is null) Do1(varA);

    else Do2(varA)
}
else
{
    if(varB is null) Do1(varB);

    else Do2(varB)
}
```

and my goal would be something like this

```
targetVar = SomeFunctionReturningAorB(condition);
{
    if(targetVar is null) Do1(targetVar);

    else Do2(targetVar);
}
```

(More details about what does DOs() and var means and what I am actually trying to achieve)

I am trying to implement an binary tree and have 2 classes like this

```
public class BinaryTree<TNode,TCost> 
{
     //Some stuff
     public void Add(TNode newNode,TCost newKey)
}

public class TreeNode<TNode,TCost> 
{
     public TreeNode? Left;//This would be VarA above 
     public TreeNode? Right;//This would be VarB above
     public TCost NodeKey;
     public TNode NodeInfo;   
}
```

Naturally, I have a couple of scenarios where same operations are applied to left node or right node, something like this :

```
//Inside the BinaryTree class in method Add

TreeNode currentNode = RootNode;
bool foundPosition = false;
while (!foundPosition)
{
   if (newKey > currentNode.NodeKey)//Go to Right Side
   {
       if (currentNode.RightChild == null)
       {
           TreeNode newLeaf = new(newNode,newKey)
           {
                Parent = currentNode
           };
           currentNode.RightChild = newLeaf;
           foundPosition = true;
        }
    else
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.RightChild;
    }
    else //Go to Left Side
    {
        if (currentNode.LeftChild == null)
        {
            TreeNode newLeaf = new(newNode,newKey)
            {
                Parent = currentNode
            };
            currentNode.LeftChild = newLeaf;
            foundPosition = true;
         }
         else
         {
             currentNode = currentNode.LeftChild;
         }
    }
}
//Some other unreleated stuff , that's why the function doesn't end at foundPosition = true;
```

So my goal as stated above is to replace this with something like

```
TreeNode currentNode = RootNode;
bool foundPosition = false;
while (!foundPosition)
{
    TreeNode? nextChild = currentNode.AppropiateChild(newKey);//Here how could I do this?
//This should return a reference to Left or Right fields of currentNode so i can change them.
    if(nextChild == null)
    {
        TreeNode newLeaf = new(newNode,newKey)
        {
            Parent = currentNode
        };
        nextChild = newLeaf;//If I dont use any refs this fails(assign to a local variable) 
        foundPosition = true;
    }
    else
    {
        currentNode = nextChild;
    }
}
//Some other unreleated stuff , that's why the function doesn't end at foundPosition = true;
```

Obviously , I could just let this be this way or find some way to rewrite it without using references to fields inside classes but now I wonder if my goal is achievable and if so then how .

I tried creating a function returning a reference to one of the fields but i failed in doing so.

```
//Inside TreeNode class
public ref TreeNode? AppropiateChild(TypeCost targetCost) 
{
    if(targetCost>this.NodeKey)
    {
        return ref RightChild;//Compilation error
    }
    else
    {
        return ref LeftChild;//Compilation error
    }
}
```

or

```
public TreeNode? AppropiateChild(TypeCost targetCost)
{
    if(targetCost>this.NodeKey)
    {
        return RightChild;
    }
    else
    {
         return LeftChild;
    }
}
```

This fails when result of this is being assigned another value.

Thank you very much

Comment: the last one is correct, how does it fail?

Comment: sgould probably be returrning `TreeNode` not `TreeNode?`

Comment: Last on fails when doing nextChild = newLeaf; as my goal is to keep nextChild as a reference to a given location in memory and such assignment should only change memory itself . But instead this changes what nextChild references to . I want to change the value nextChild is referencing to without changing the reference . But i just can't find how.

Comment: TreeNode? is justified beacause there are cases where there are no TreeNodes for either child or parent (Root has null as parent while leafs -terminal nodes- have null as children)